# How to get HTML5 Canvas.todataurl file size in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
var data_url=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

var img=$("#img").attr("src",data_url);
```

what is the **img** file size in kb?

Comment: What file ? There's no file here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to know the size of the data-url in bytes you can do:

`var imgFileSize = data_url.length;`

But that's not the real size of the png size. You can approximate very accurately to the real PNG size this way:

```
var head = 'data:image/png;base64,';
var imgFileSize = Math.round((data_url.length - head.length)*3/4) ;
```

Because the Base64 encoding has a 4/3 overhead.

**Edit:** corrected the size calculation after comments.

Comment: Sorry! The Base64 has a 4/3 overhead so the original file is 3/4 times smaller than the Base64. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: If Base64=4/3*Original, then Original=3/4*Base64

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right. And I don't know math anymore... :-| what a messy week this has been (hmm).

Comment: how to get the size in mb

Comment: @CraZyDroiD `Math.round((data_url.length - head.length) * 3 / 4) / 1024 / 1024`

Comment: Good slution and i found it rather accurate, but not always 100% correct.
Why is there a discrepancy? why is this a good approximation and not the exact value?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein because base64 strings can add some padding

Answer (score 15):

> base64 estimates will always vary! Decode the base64 string and check its length. This method is always 100% accurate!

Once you strip off the MIME type (via [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and decode the string (via [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob)), the resulting string length should be identical to the final filesize.

```
let size_in_bytes = window.atob(base64.split(",")[1]).length;
```

Answer (score 6):

Best way to think about it is that each char represents 6 bits (2^**6** == 64, hence the Base**64**). So times the amount of chars you have by 6 to get the total number of bits. Then divide the total number of bits by 8 to get the amount of bytes, because a byte is 8 bits.

`Math.round(base64String.length * 6 / 8);`

Which is the same as `Math.round(base64String.length * 3 / 4);`.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find that Pedro's solution accurate, what i did was to create a blob out of the canvas and then get the fileSize

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    alert(blob.size);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Endless This works for me as well,    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
            document.getElementById("NewFsize").innerHTML = "New size: "+(blob.size)/1000000 + " Mbytes" 
        });

Comment: how can you return?

Comment: it's async/callback based so you can't return the value... you can wrap it in a promise doe and use async/await